# unzip password protected zip in unix

Tags: shell, unix, unzip

I need to create a shell script wherein I will unzip a password protected zip file. I know the password, and need to automate the unzip process.

How can I achieve this using Unix shell scripting?

Comment: If you are going to hard-code a password in a script, I assume this means that (1) you are in control of the creation of the .zip file and (2) this file will be created (on one computer) and decompressed (on another computer) many times since you want to script it.  If so, have you considered not using file-level encryption, and instead using secure transmission (e.g. with SSH) over the network using private/public keys in a way that avoids having to type passwords?

Answer (score 105):

```
unzip -P your-password zipfile.zip
```

[man unzip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip)

> -P password
>
> use password to decrypt encrypted zipfile entries (if any). THIS IS INSECURE! Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any
> user to see the current command line of any other user; even on
> stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder
> peeking. Storing the plaintext password as part of a command line in
> an automated script is even worse. Whenever possible, use the
> non-echoing, interactive prompt to enter passwords. (And where
> security is truly important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good
> Privacy instead of the relatively weak encryption provided by standard
> zipfile utilities.)

Comment: I also had the same problem, but your command didn't work. `7z x archive.zip -ppassword` command did work.

Comment: `need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.6)`

Comment: I just found out that it depends on the encryption wether this works. As this does not work for AES-256 encryption. But it works for ZipCrypto (which seems to be default)

Comment: thank you - i am surprised there is not a corresponding double-dash command such as: 
"--password"

Comment: If you need to extract hundreds of password-protected files at once, [here's an answer I just added on how to parallelize and speed up the operation with `find`, `xargs`, and `unar -p`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76910116/4561887).

Answer (score 39):

In Ubuntu, I've to install 7zip (7z) archive tool using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Then, you can use Ubuntu's default *Archive Manager* to unzip the password protected zip files

Comment: Normally I prefer CLI, however, 7-Zip supported higher encryption version than the default unzip. It is also useful to be able to double click.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 25):

I ran into problem using `unzip` saying `need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.6)`.
Installed `p7zip` instead and unzipped using following command:

```
7z x archive.zip -ppassword
```

Answer (score 12):

To unzip multiple password protected files, this command **WILL NOT WORK**

```
unzip -P PASSWORD *.zip
```

To make it work, you need to include the `*.zip` in quotes because whenever you use a wildcard (*), the shell itself will expand that and pass the results to the program. This is because, unlike most programs in UNIX, unzip cannot take more than one file at a time.

Read more here https://chrisjean.com/unzip-multiple-files-from-linux-command-line/.

Therefore, to  unzip multiple protected files, use this

```
unzip -P PASSWORD  '*.zip'
```

Comment: It returns `error:  must give decryption password with -P option`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Please follow bellow instruction, i have solved same problem by following these steps.

1. `sudo apt install p7zip-full`
2. `7z x example.zip`
3. it will ask password for your zip file, provide password and let the process complete

Visit the following URL: [For more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13474/how-do-i-extract-a-password-protected-7z-file)

Answer (score 3):

After banging my head on the wall many times, here's my two-cent.

If the password you received contains special characters such as $ ; \ etc, your shell terminal might interpret it as part of the shell special symbol and not exactly the password string that you intended it to be.

Solution is simple, enclosed the password in a single quote!

`7z x [yourzipfile] -P'your$pass;word!'`

I hope this help save your time when suddenly it seems like your zip/unzip encrypted password did not work!

Answer (score 0):

### Unzip or extract one password-protected file

*This also answers the question, "How do you extract a .zip file into a subdirectory or nested subdirectories, automatically creating them if they don't exist?"*

`unar` (un-archive) works well. So, you can use `unar` *or* `unzip`, like this. Note that it is a *lowercase* `-p` with `unar`, but it is an *uppercase* `-P` with `unzip`:

```bash
# (my preference) Unzip all contents of myfile.zip into a directory it creates
# which it names `myfile`, after the `myfile.zip` file itself
unar -p my_password path/to/myfile.zip
# Unzip all contents of myfile.zip into a directory it creates which is named
# `some_other_dir/myfile`, where `some_other_dir` is a name you choose, and
# `myfile` is a directory it automatically names based on the `myfile.zip` zip
# file.
# - Note that neither `some_other_dir` *nor* directory `myfile` have to exist
#   for this to work. If they don't exist, `unar` creates them automatically
#   for you!
unar -p my_password path/to/myfile.zip -o some_other_dir

# Unzip all contents of myfile.zip directly into the current directory, rather
# than into a sub-directory
unzip -P my_password path/to/myfile.zip
# Unzip myfile.zip into dir myfile/
unzip -P my_password -d myfile path/to/myfile.zip
```

I learned about the `-d some/directory` option with `unzip` here: [How to extract a zip file to a specific folder?](https://askubuntu.com/a/520555/327339).

I prefer `unar` over `unzip` simply because `unar` automatically unzips the contents into a folder by the same name as the file, which is convenient and prevents me from misplacing the extracted files. It also has the `-o some_other_dir` option, as explained above, which is really nice to extract a ton of zip files into their own unique folders inside `some_other_dir`.

### Unzip many password-protected files *in parallel* via `find`, `xargs`, and `unar`

If you're unzipping hundreds or even thousands of files at once, you can parallelize the operation with `xargs` to spawn one process per CPU core you have (as shown by `nproc`) until all files are done. This makes it *much much* faster! Here is how:

```bash
# Unzip many password-protected files at once, assuming they all have the same
# password

# GENERALLY WHAT I USE:
# - Note: `-maxdepth 1` causes this to only unzip *top-level* .zip files within
#   your current directory
time find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} \
    -n 1 -P $(nproc) unar -p my_password -f {}

# Or, remove `-maxdepth 1` to unzip *all* .zip files, recursively, which are
# found within your current directory or lower.
time find . -type f -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} \
    -n 1 -P $(nproc) unar -p my_password -f {}

# You can also output ALL extracted folders into their own unique output dir
# named `some_other_dir`, with the `-o` flag. 
# - `some_other_dir` does *not* have to exist before-hand!--it will
#   automatically create it for you!
time find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} \
    -n 1 -P $(nproc) unar -p my_password -f {} -o some_other_dir
# or (without `-maxdepth 1`)
time find . -type f -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} \
    -n 1 -P $(nproc) unar -p my_password -f {} -o some_other_dir

# ALSO VERY USEFUL!
# To extract all .zip files at path `some_dir/*.zip` into dir
# `some_dir/some_other_dir/*/[all files]`, you must do this:
# 1. Pass `some_dir` to `find`, and 
# 2. Pass `-o some_dir/some_other_dir` to `unar`: 
time find some_dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} \
    -n 1 -P $(nproc) unar -p my_password -f {} -o some_dir/some_other_dir
# or (without `-maxdepth 1`)
time find some_dir -type f -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} \
    -n 1 -P $(nproc) unar -p my_password -f {} -o some_dir/some_other_dir
```

The first command above just unzipped 93 similar ~2 MB files for me in **1.084 seconds**. That's 1.084 sec/93 files = **0.012 sec** per file. `nproc` shows that I have 20 cores.

If I run it single-threaded/single-process, all in serial instead of parallel, by changing `-P $(nproc)` to `-P 1` instead, I end up with this command (`time find . -type f -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} -n 1 -P $(nproc) unar -p my_password -f {}`) which takes **9.246 sec** instead. That's 9.246 sec/93 files = **0.099 sec** per file, which is 0.099/0.012 = **8.25x slower.**

Just for fun, I also ran a serial unzip command, `time unzip -o -P my_password '*.zip'` (note that `-o` is dangerous and means "overwrite" existing files), as a speed comparison. It took **8.196 sec** on my 93 files, also much slower than the multi-process `unar` command above which took **1.084 seconds**, and even worse, it created a massive, unusable mess of extracted files piled up on top of each other everywhere in the same directory.

So, use the parallel forms above where I pipe `find` to `xargs` and `unar`.

### References

1. I learned `unzip -P my_password path/to/myfile.zip` [in the main answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42186570/4561887).
2. My answer on [How to unzip multiple files at once](https://askubuntu.com/a/1479490/327339), where I first wrote about piping `find` to `xargs` and `unar` for parallel extracting operations.